# js sessionStorage: QuotaExceededError

Tags: javascript, session-storage

The error message show on chrome console: `sessionStorage: QuotaExceededError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'image' exceeded the quota.`

How to fix it and let saving images work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

your device internal storage has no enough empty space try to empty some space